# LINQ statement with where clause not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create LINQ statement. with where clause like this

```
  p.Users = db.UserFSMs
      .Where(t => t.UserName.Contains(userORFile.Split('_')[2]))
      .Select(new Models.UsersFSMFinal { Email=t.Email });
```

But the compiler is not recognizing `t`. How can I create above query that will work with where?

Comment: Just syntax error. You should read about lamba syntax here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

- you have to declare `t=>` again with the `.Select(t => new`
- I wrote the same LINQ statement but on my Database and the inserted
  data will be from a textbox. It worked fine

  ```
   var allData = db.Patients
       .Where(t => t.firstName.Contains(TextBox1.Text))
       .Select(t => new
       {
            t.firstName,
            t.lastName
       });
  ```

Comment: I am not inserting into database, I am sending data to view. so I can't send `var` typed to view I need concrete type.

Comment: @Alex While this is not the best formulated answer, it's technically correct. Just read the beginning - insert `t =>` in your `Select`. Then you'll get a runtime exception, but that's another story.